# Password error when I want deploy my website

Tags: ruby, symfony, capistrano, capifony

I have installed my project on a new comptuter. This project have Capifony (Capistrano). But now, when I want update my website with "cap deploy", I get this error :

> [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: 37.***.***.*** (ArgumentError: Value(s) have been set to nil: password)
>   connection failed for: 37.**.**.*** (ArgumentError: Value(s) have been set to nil: password)

My configuration file has not changed is the same as on my old computer ... I don't understand. Thanks :)

Comment: I have the same problem. Updated my vm and now getting this error. If you'll find a solution please post it here.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this with help of my colleagues. In my case i had `net-ssh` gem installed of version `4.0.0.alpha4`. What I had to do is to downgrade it to `3.1.1`.

`sudo gem install net-ssh --version 3.1.1`

Then uninstall newer version:

`sudo gem uninstall net-ssh`

Choose option `1. net-ssh-4.0.0.alpha4`